# VirtualBox Win7 window squeezed

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Here's been a really weird thing in VirtualBox hosting Win7 Professional.

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

The window has been squeezed so that i cannot login.

Here's a screenshot of the view mode:

[image]

I tried all of them, none of them works.

Hosting on OSX 10.8.3, VirtualBox version 4.2.16.

Any ideas folks? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the guest additions installed?

Comment: The window can be adjusted have you tried adusting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final solution is simple.

Start windows using safe mode, setting the account to login without need to type the password. Then restart the vm, as it enters the squeezed screen it will login in itself, and then just resize the window to normal size.

Next time it will remember the previous size so no need to resize the window again.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the settings for the `Win7 Professional` VM, make sure the allocated `Video Memory` is not a 0 MB. You shouldn't need more than 50 MB for it to display correctly.

You could also try Enabling `3D Acceleration` to see if that helps.

If that doesn't help you may need to re-install VirtualBox.

Comment: it was good before, but all of a sudden after a restart of Win7 it became like this, the Video Memory is 128M, Enable both 3D and 2D Accelerations. Won't help.

Comment: You could re-install Virtual Box and re-load the VM after the re-install.